# How to put an threshold of .8 to Random forest classifier In Python

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am doing a binary classification problem. I want put a threshold .8 to be classified as a particular class. If the probability falls below .8 classify into another class. How can this be done .

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10, max_depth=8 ,random_state=0)
classifier = clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
predictions = classifier.predict_proba(X_train) 
predict=pd.DataFrame(predictions)
```

**Dataframe after combining with Probabilty**

```
Id  Gender  Age Salary  country Mix_ratio   Allowance   0   1
3452    M   25  245689  AU     0.46             7880    0.8 0.2
890     F   43  568909  FR     0.23             89076   0.7 0.3
4670    M   29  897643  AU     0.76             7865    0.1 0.9
7423    F   32  235892  IND    0.45             78534   0.2 0.8
94567   F   56  145823  SG     0.67             54123   0.5 0.5
23876   M   56  345122  FR     0.23              8900   0.8 0.2
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: predict_proba will return the most likely class of the classifier. so setting a threshold wouldn't make sense. instead try experimenting with class weights. More [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/11564/how-does-class-weights-work-in-randomforestclassifier)

Comment: @skrubber,how would class weights help in this case. Can you briefly explain

Answer (score 0):

Using your DataFrame, you can do something like:

```
df['outcome'] = np.where(df['1']>=0.8, 'Class A', 'Class B')

df
Out[88]: 
      Id Gender  Age  Salary country  Mix_ratio  Allowance    0    1  outcome
0   3452      M   25  245689      AU       0.46       7880  0.8  0.2  Class B
1    890      F   43  568909      FR       0.23      89076  0.7  0.3  Class B
2   4670      M   29  897643      AU       0.76       7865  0.1  0.9  Class A
3   7423      F   32  235892     IND       0.45      78534  0.2  0.8  Class A
4  94567      F   56  145823      SG       0.67      54123  0.5  0.5  Class B
5  23876      M   56  345122      FR       0.23       8900  0.8  0.2  Class B
```

Comment: this is a rule based system. can we do something from the algorithm side